# .htaccess wildcard redirect for images only, from root directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm redoing a site and have to change the directory structure. Here's an outline of what I have:

```
Web root            <- This is the only location for the .htaccess file
|  + OldDir         <- To be deleted, but...
|   |  + SubDir     <- ...all folders/images from OldDir to be moved to NewDir below
|   |   |  + 0001
|   |   |   | foo.gif
|   |   |   | bar.jpg
|   |   |  + 0002
|   |   |  + ...etc.
|  + NewDir         <- All images and folders from SubDir will be moved here
|   |  + 0001
|   |   | foo.gif
|   |   | bar.jpg
|   |  + 0002
|   |  + ...etc.
```

Notice the folders and their images will end up one level higher in the directory tree. Basically, the end result is for "SubDir" to be renamed and moved to be a direct sub-directory of the web root.

In case it's relevant, all of the directories under "SubDir" follow the same naming convention of four numerical characters, as shown above.

Please note that I can only place the .htaccess file in the web root.

The catch is that I'm using a CMS that will use "virtual directories," one of which will be called "OldDir" (and cannot actually exist). So I can't just grab *everything* in OldDir and redirect it to NewDir, because the current URLs will still exist in the CMS. I've got to get just the images.

I'm no stranger to .htaccess, but apparently I'm not enough of an expert to combine all these factors together into a working redirect rule. Would appreciate any thoughts as to what work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule for this should suffice:

```bash
RewriteRule ^OldDir/SubDir/(\d{4}/.+.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))$ /NewDir/$1 [R=301,L]
```